# What is the difference between standard and slim or wide angle filters?

Tags: lens, filters

I want to buy a clear filter for my Sony FE 24–240 mm F3.5-6.3 OSS lens and my choice is B+W 72MM XS-PRO CLEAR filter.

But I am confused between slim/wide angle and standard ones. Which will be the best for the lens?

Comment: "Which will be the best for the lens?" Neither. The idea that filters offer protection beyond keeping out dirt, dust, moisture, and other microscopic flying objects is a myth. They don't. So is the idea that a minor scratch on the front element will materially affect the optical image quality of the lens. It won't.

Answer (score 2):

Slim filters have thinner rims which are intended to cause less potential vignetting issues with, in particular, wide angle lenses.

I am personally of the opinion that no clear filter is the correct choice for normal shooting, unless you are shooting in dirty settings ( mud, sandy beach perhaps, near sea spray ).  In the absence of these conditions all you're doing is introducing a layer of glass that the lens was not designed for.

Some people consider these protection devices.  I don't find them useful myself in that way.

Which type (slim or normal) is best for your lens is a matter I can't be very specific on.  Your lens is not unusually wide, (24mm), but is a little wide than a standard zoom (which would be 28mm typically at the wide end).  If, however, you intend to use the lens with the filter on all the time then I'd recommend the slim type as you should minimize the potential for vignetting unless you can test the issue before buying.